# Getting syntaxError: Unexpected identifier and Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I wrote  function called replaceImg() which replaces the img in the tag td witdh 
his alternative text.But I get two errors which are :

Uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected identifier

and second

Uncaught ReferenceError:replaceImg is not defined

thanks for the help !

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd"
                 xml:lang="en" >
                 <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Convert me!</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function replaceImg(){

            var imgarray = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            var td       = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            var x;

            for(var i=0;i < imgarray.length;i++){

            var x = i;

            var img    = imgarray[x];

            var p      = document.createTextNode(imgarray[x].alt);

            var r      = td[x].replaceChild(p,img);
}
}
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <table width="600" border="0">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><img height="100" alt="Schadenfreude" src="ausdruck_1.gif" width="100" /></td>
                <td align="center"><img height="100" alt="Erstaunen" src="ausdruck_2.gif" width="100" /></td>
                <td align="center"><img height="100" alt="Skepsis" src="ausdruck_3.gif" width="100" /></td>
                <td align="center"><img height="100" alt="Betretenheit" src="ausdruck_4.gif" width="100" /></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="button" value="ersetze Bilder" onclick="replaceImg()"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center">ist die schönste Freude, kann aber Feinde 
                schaffen</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">gebar die Philosophie und wird von 
                Rechthabern immer wieder unterschätzt</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">ist bisweilen angebracht, sollte aber nicht 
                das weitere Dazulernen behindern</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">ist sehr unangenehm, währt aber nicht ewig</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are trying to accomplish with that change. All you are doing is using a new variable `x` but it has the exact same value as `i` each iteration...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's clear that you have experience in other programming languages because you are using a different syntax for your `for` loop.

```
for(int i=0;i < imgarray.length;i++)
//---^
```

That is not valid JavaScript. You should try something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i < imgarray.length;i++)
```

JavaScript has loosely typed variable which means you don't have to define their type when initializing them. All you have to do is give them a value.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply ,I changed it to var but it´s still not working :(

Comment: That means that `img[i]` is undefined. You should fix these errors first before continuing.

Comment: Sorry for those stupid questions but we declare var i as 0 in the first round so it should be img[0].alt and this should work ,isn´t it?

Comment: Only if `img[0]` exists and has an `alt` property :)

Comment: var img would not be an array it would contain the value of imgarray[0].

Comment: I changed my function tho this :

Comment: @user3057253 - you can click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20327463/edit) button on your post to add more details to your original question.

Comment: ahhh sorry i replaced it :( .

Comment: I looked to the chrome developer console and build everything .this supposed to work :(

Comment: But you're not getting any errors now? If the only problem is with the logic, you'll have to sit and debug it a little bit more - there is not much I can do from over here to fix the logic :)